# meteor server side login with iron router

Tags: authentication, meteor, iron-router

I want to create a server side login, for my client app use iron router : server.
but until now i don't find any clue how to do that. yet, i use reststop2, but now he said to use iron router.

this is my simple code :

```
Router.route('/api/signin', {where: 'server'})
    .get(function () {
        this.response.end('get request\n');
    })
    .post(function () {
        console.log(this.request.body.username);//or email maybe
        console.log(this.request.body.password);
        this.response.end('post request\n');
    });
```

i send or post data using json from body, thats why i use `this.request.body.*` .

and now let me know, how to use that username and password to login in server side?

FYI, in reststop2 i just use `localhost:3000/api/login` and send data username and password, after that i get return `access token` and `user id`.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use iron:router to build an API:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('/api/login/:username/:password', {
        where : 'server,
        action : function(){
            //your code goes here
        }
    }
});
```

I would always choose an package that implements an API instead of iron:router but for simple server-side stuff iron:route will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I published an open-source package for writing REST APIs in Meteor 0.9.0+, and I think it might be exactly what you are looking for. I ran into the same problem when RestStop2 was deprecated:

https://github.com/krose72205/meteor-restivus

It was inspired by [RestStop2](http://github.differential.com/reststop2/) and built with [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-route)'s server-side routing. It's very easy to convert to if you're already using RestStop2.